# From Chebyshev's inequality to a bound on a random variable

Tags: probability

I encountered a claim that I don't understand.

Suppose a random variable X is a mean of n random variables, has a finite expected value $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$. Suppose also that $\sigma = \frac{c}{\sqrt{n}}$ for some positive constant c.

Chebyshev's inequality states that $P(|X-\mu|>k\sigma) \leq \frac{1}{k^2}$ for any positive k.

How, then, it is inferred  [here](http://www.gautamkamath.com/CS860notes/lec3.pdf) that $|X-\mu| \leq O(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$?

I don't understand how to get from a bound on a probability to a bound on the random variable itself?
Thanks.

Comment: The statement $|X - \mu| \leq c/\sqrt{n}$ holds with high probability. It wouldn't be always true.

Comment: I guess that the big $O$ shoud be understood as a big $O$ in probability. See Wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_in_probability_notation